# compare two strings and assign score in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I need to know whether we can compare 2 string of different length and check the substring is occured in given sring or not

For example:

```
str1='abcdef '
str2='acbcdef'
```

here length are same but letter is different how can i assign score for this

Comment: What do you mean by `how can i assign score for this` ? what do you expect as an output ?

Comment: i got the answer bro thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `difflib`:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
str1='abcdef '
str2='acbcdef'
print(similar(str1,str2))
```

Output:

```
0.8571428571428571
```